# Was bedeutet »Dem Ausdruck zufolge«?

Tags: meaning, translation

Könnte mir bitte jemand den Sinn dieses folgenden Abschnitts erklären:

> … dass der Zufall darin lag, dass ein Bewohner dieses Hauses – dem Ausdruck zufolge eine Familie Wright – überhaupt an einen Kontoauszug gekommen war, ehe …

Mir geht nämlich den Teil zwischen den Gedankenstrichen nicht in den Kopf: »dem Ausdruck zufolge eine Familie Wright«

Answer (score 11):

Nachdem es sich um einen Kontoauszug - also etwas **gedrucktes** - zu handeln scheint, ist *Ausdruck* hier wohl nicht etwa mit "expression", sondern eher mit "printout" zu übersetzen - Das ist eine mögliche Mehrdeutigkeit, über die du gestolpert sein könntest (Ich denke mal, Englisch hilft dir weiter, obwohl ich deine Muttersprache nicht kenne).

Damit ergibt sich im Englischen die fast wörtliche Übersetzung

> some Family Wright, according to the printout

für den Teilsatz zwischen den Gedankenstrichen.

Comment: Danke. Habe diese Moeglichkeit ausgeschlossen, aber Ich sehe jetzt ein das dass was Sie behaupten, waerht.

Answer (score 6):

In diesem Kontext ist ein *Ausdruck* ein Stück Papier, auf das etwas ausgedruckt wurde. Ein Ausdruck ist also das, was aus einem Drucker herauskommt.

Dem Zitat ist zu entnehmen, dass es sich bei diesem Ausdruck um einen Kontoauszug handelt, und auf diesem Stück Papier steht offenbar der Name *Wright*.

Das Wort *zufolge* gibt an, dass ein logischer Schluss gezogen wird: Auf dem Ausdruck steht der Name *Wright*, daher kann man daraus schließen, dass die Bewohner des Hauses *Wright* heißen.

Comment: Dem zweiten Absatz würde ich widersprechen. Es ist nicht sicher, ob der erwähnte Ausdruck auch der Kontoauszug ist. Es könnte auch ein beliebiges anderes gedrucktes Schriftstück sein, aus dem der genannte Sachverhalt hervorgeht.